# runtime error for hankerrank's 'Alternating Characters'

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures

This is code for hankerrank's problem "Alternating Character". This code is good on my system.and it clearing all the TESTCASEs, but in hankerrank, it throughs runtime error. Runtime error is

```
Compiler Message
Runtime Error
Error (stderr)
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
at Solution.main(Solution.java:17)
```

this is my code.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Solution4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner tin=new Scanner(System.in);
    int tc=in.nextInt();
    String [] strA=new String[tc];
   // System.out.println("strL"+strA.length);
    for(int i=0;i<strA.length;i++){
          strA[i]=tin.nextLine();
         // System.out.print(" i= "+i+" sr = "+strA[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<strA.length;i++){
         String str=strA[i];
         int k=0;
         int d=0;
         for(int j=1;j<str.length();j++){

             if(str.charAt(k)==str.charAt(j))
                  d++;
             else
                k=j; 
         }
         System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What's the input that you tried?

Comment: Sample Input

5
AAAA
BBBBB
ABABABAB
BABABA
AAABBB
Sample Output

3
4
0
0
4

Comment: here 5 is no. of input

Comment: no, each in separate line, even output too

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/alternating-characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if less input is supplied,your code won't work.Try using

```
for(int i=0;i<strA.length;i++){
      if(tin.hasNextLine())
        strA[i]=tin.nextLine();
      else
      {
        System.out.println("An error occured");
        return;
      }
    }
```

Or if that didn't work out well,try changing your whole code to:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Solution4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner tin=new Scanner(System.in);
    int tc=in.nextInt();
    String [] strA=new String[tc];

    for(int i=0;i<strA.length;i++){
      if(tin.hasNextLine()) //if input is there
        strA[i]=tin.nextLine();
    }       

    for(int i=0;i<strA.length;i++){
         int d=0;
         if(strA[i]!=null) //this will be true when the input is less
         {
           String str=strA[i];
           int k=0;
           for(int j=1;j<str.length();j++){
               if(str.charAt(k)==str.charAt(j))
                    d++;
               else
                  k=j; 
           }
         }
     System.out.println(d);
   }
}
```

}

Comment: now i'm getting " An error occured ", could you explain me,why is it. I excuted on my system, it is fine. then why it is not on hankerrank

Comment: Hackerrank is giving only some amount of input which is less than the required amount of input. If this is not the message you want then check try the code I posted

Comment: then what should i do? how did you figure out that it would not work with less input? I'm curious about to know.

Comment: @sa8 , Read the error message.It clearly says "No line found" which means that Hackerrank supplied less input. Without any more input left,`strA[i]=tin.nextLine();` threw an exception. Try out the code in my answer

Comment: Your code is fine on my system but not on hankerrank.  wrong answer is message on hankerrank

Comment: it not giving any runtime error but not even answer, hankerRank show "wrong answer"

Comment: @sa8 , If this is not working,then I don't know what is causing the "wrong answer"

Comment: this is working on my system but not on hankerrank, I'm also not able to figure out to this problem

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s;
        int t;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        t = in.nextInt();

        for (int f = 0; f < t; ++f) {
            s = in.next();
            getResult(s);
        }
        in.close(); 
    }

    public static void getResult(String s){
        char[] cArr;

        cArr = s.toCharArray();
        int delCount = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<cArr.length-1;i++){
            if(cArr[i]==cArr[i+1]){ 
                delCount++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(delCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/alternating-character][1]s

This should work.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        //For each test case
        for(byte T = Byte.parseByte(br.readLine()); T > 0; --T){

            //Solve
            sb.append(getMinDeletions(br.readLine().toCharArray()) + "\n");
        }
        System.out.print(sb);
    }

    private static int getMinDeletions(final char[] S){
        int deletions = 0;
        for(int i = 1, N = S.length; i < N; ++i){
            if(S[i] == S[i-1]){
                ++deletions;
            }
        }
        return deletions;
    }
}
```